# How to calculate the local zenith angle?

Tags: astronomy

I am reading the "*GOES-R Advanced Baseline Imager (ABI) Algorithm Theoretical Basis Document For Fire/Hot Spot Characterization*" which is a pdf about Fire/Hot Spot production produced with goes-r ABI dataset. In this pdf, it uses the decision rule "Solar zenith angle <= 70˚ OR (Solar zenith angle <= 60˚ AND local zenith angle <= 60˚)".

I know that the definition of the "solar zenith angle" is "The solar zenith angle is the angle between the zenith and the centre of the Sun's disc." according to **Wikipedia**. But considering that the "solar zenith angle" and "local zenith angle" are present at the same time in the above decision rule, there should be some differences between these two angles. I do not understand the "local zenith angle", and have the following two questions.

How to calculate the local zenith angle? what's the difference between the local zenith angle and solar zenith angle? Thanks!

Comment: Could it relate to the zenith angle of a sensing satellite?